# Works in Debug mode but not when publish. How to solve that?

Tags: asp.net, azure, text-to-speech, razor-pages

Good evening,

Before all, I precise that I'm a novice and I'm very sorry if my question is really stupid but I couldn't find any answer online.

I am trying to build a web app with a voice agent using Azure resources.

So far, I have a basic web app using ASP.NET 5.0 and a voice agent. When I run the app in the debug, and click on the button I've build to activate the voice, it works, you can ear the agent speaking. However, when I publish the app on Chrome or edge, there is no sound anymore even if it looks like the button works because at the end of the url "?handler=button" appears.

Here is the code for the cshtml file:

```
@model IndexModel
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}
<div>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
    <p>The time on the server is @DateTime.Now</p>
</div>

<div>
    <h2>Weather Aria</h2>
    <p>
        @Model.Message
    </p>
</div>
<div>
    <form asp-page-handler="button" method="post">
        <button class="btn btn-default">CLICK ME</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

and here is the code for the Index.cshtml.cs file:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech;
using Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.Audio;


namespace MySecondAzureWebApp.Pages
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        public static async Task SynthesizeAudioAsync()
        {
            //configure subscription: key + location
            var config = SpeechConfig.FromSubscription("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "westeurope");
            using var synthesizer = new SpeechSynthesizer(config);
            await synthesizer.SpeakTextAsync("Hello, I'm Aria, can you hear me ?");
        }

        public string Message { get; private set; } = "Aria starts talking. Can you hear her?";

       public void OnGet()
        {
             Message += $" Server time is { DateTime.Now }";
        }
        public async Task OnPost()
        {
            await SynthesizeAudioAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Do you know where the problem comes from and how I can solve it ?

I've read online that this might have something to do with the server but I don't have any idea of how to change it. And I don't even know if this is the case since I'm only using azure.

I would greatly appreciate any help,
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you make sure that your browser tab isn't on mute?

Comment: I have checked that already ^^. Now I have made minors changes on the code and I have this error message "An error occurred while processing your request.
Development Mode
Swapping to the Development environment displays detailed information about the error that occurred.

The Development environment shouldn't be enabled for deployed applications. It can result in displaying sensitive information from exceptions to end users. For local debugging, enable the Development environment by setting the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT environment variable to Development and restarting the app."

Answer (score 0):

If deploying to Azure while still in development, then you can set the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT to Development in the Application settings

[image]